# Find all files that do not have the sticky bit set for which the file is executable on my FreeBSD Server

Tags: unix, freebsd

How do I get a list of only files (no directories) on my FreeBSD Server that do not have the sticky bit set and for which the file is executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
find . \! -perm -01000 -perm -00100 -perm -00010 -perm -00001 \! -type l \! -type d -print
```

You might want to invest some time in learning the intricacies of find. Alvin Alexander blog post [Linux find command recipes](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/linux-find-command-recipes-faqs-common-examples) is a place you might start and just google `unix find` for more.